# How to get type inference using a utility type, or type parameter, when I extend the built-in array class?

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-class

---

### Defining types for Class-member's in an Extended Array Class

---

So below, you can see that I extend the array class via the `WillyWonka` class. The problem is, when I do it as shown below, I get no type inference for the items stored in the array.

My biggest concern is that the array prototype implements exotic properties, making it a special, and somewhat unique, class to extend. I am extending it the same way I would in JS, and add the values to the Array using
`Object.assign(this, sumOmpaLoompas);`.
There are other ways to add items into the array, which I tried, but type inference was not gained. This is why I feel like I should be using a type parameter or utility type.

```
/*
---------------("DOCUMENT #1")--------------- */
type OmpaLoompa = {
  name: string,
  work: ()=> string
}

type OmpaLoompas = OmpaLoompa[];


class WillyWonka extends Array{
  constructor(sumOmpaLoompas: OmpaLoompas){
    super();
    Object.assign(this, sumOmpaLoompas);
  }
}

const ompaLoompas = [
  {
    name: 'Frank the Frightened Ompa',
    work: ()=> 'Produced Chocolate'
  },
  {

    name: 'Fran the Frail Loompa',
    work: ()=> 'Produced Carmel'
  },
  {
    name: 'Larry the Lazy Ompa',
    work: ()=> 'Didn\'t Produce Today'
  },
  {
    name: 'Linda the Lovely Loompa',
    work: ()=> 'Produced Wafers'
  }
];
/*


---------------("DOCUMENT #2")--------------- */
const wonkyWilly = new WillyWonka(ompaLoompas);
const ompaLoompaAtZero = wonkyWilly[0];
const ompaLoompaAtTwo = wonkyWilly[2];

console.log(ompaLoompaAtZero); //       <-- TYPE = ANY (I need this to be "type: OmpaLoompa")
console.log(ompaLoompaAtTwo.work()); // <-- TYPE = ANY (I need this to be "type: OmpaLoompa.work")

// EXPECTED OUTPUT:
// { name: 'Frank the Frightened Ompa', work: [Function: work] }
// Didn't Produce Today
```

#### SUMMARIZING

---

1. In the example above there is a class `WillyWonka` that extends the `Array` class.
2. The classes constructor takes a single argument of a well defined type.
3. Then `Object.assign(...)` is used to add the iteratable objects from the constructors argument, as properties to the class, so the properties can be accessed, and iterated through using the extended array class.

#### Here's My Problem

---

Maybe I am writing the class wrong, to be honest I don't really know if this is the best way to go about defining a custom array object. It seems to work for all intents and purposes, except for one — and being that it is TypeScript, its sort of a big one — **Type Inference**. I was hoping that the TSC could infer the types so that when I import the `WillyWonka` class from one document to the next, it would know that `willyWonka[0]` was of the type `OmpaLoompa`, but TSC just annotates it as being `any`. If this wasn't an API that others will use, I probably would just deal with it, but I have to assume that others will use this Lib/API. So, at this point, if you have kept up with me, then my question should be pretty straight forward.

> ***"How can I define the types for the properties on the custom WillyWonka extended array class?"***

I am open to using another mechanism than `Object.assign(...)`, so long as I can still access the OmpaLoompa typed properties as `willyWonka[i:number]`

Oh one other detail, I want the classes to be inferred to the imported class, in-other-words;

Do you see the comment that says, "`/* DOCUMENT #1 */`", and the other that says, "`/* DOCUMENT #2 */`"? I can't be coerced into typing the array's properties in document #2, because document two is an example of the Lib/API being used, the only part I will write is document #1. I need the types already defined when any arbitrary developer writes document #2 using the WillyWonk API.

---

I am pr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix: just add `OmpaLoompa` to the generic parameter of `Array`.

```js
class WillyWonka extends Array<OmpaLoompa> { /* ... */ }
```

Otherwise TypeScript will assume that the elements of `Array` are of type `any`.

Comment: Damn, that was easy as hell. I've still got some learning to do obviously. Thanks Tobias.